# Setting user environment variable

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have a number of batch files to run that depend on an environment variable. Up to now the setting of the environment variable has been done manually. I wish to automate this by running a VC++ program to compute the setting and update the environment variable.

Problems:

1. When the VC++ program runs it only gets a copy of the environment. I can successfully set variables but they are lost when the program exits.
2. I then used the Regxxx functions to write the setting in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" followed by
   `rStat = SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,(LPARAM)"Environment",SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, &dwReturnVal);`

   This reports success and the change can be inspected using regedit. However if I launch a new cmd.exe shell the environment has not been updated.
3. If I inspect using SystemPropertiesAdvanced tool the new values are seen and after exit a new cmd.exe shell sees them.

Microsoft docs say the broadcast message should cause the changes to be recognised but it does not work.

Any suggestion gratefully received.

```
TCHAR newName[] = _T("cock of the walk");
DWORD newNameSize = sizeof(newName);
HKEY hKey;
LSTATUS stat;
stat = RegCreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Environment"), &hKey);
if (stat == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    TCHAR val[200];
    DWORD bufsiz = 100;
    stat = RegGetValue(hKey, NULL, _T("donkeykong"), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, val, &bufsiz);
    if ((stat == ERROR_SUCCESS) || (stat = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND))
    {
        stat = RegSetKeyValue(hKey, NULL, _T("donkeykong"), REG_SZ, newName, newNameSize);
        DWORD_PTR dwReturnVal;
        LRESULT rStat;
        rStat = SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)"Environment",
            SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, &dwReturnVal);
        std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
    }
    stat = RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

Comment: Chances are that you are using a Unicode build. You are passing an ANSI string to `SendMessageTimeout()` though. Try this: `SendMessageTimeoutW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM) L"Environment",
            SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, &dwReturnVal);`

Comment: @zett42 Thank you. Bang on the money